# Why does my view become white when i remove a subview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

in my view I have a scrollView as subview. The scrollView has another subview called thePDFView. It is for showing a PDF page.
This view has 2 subviews. drawImage is an image loaded from disk above the whole PDF view.
And paintView is the second subview where all the painting and markup is done.
But I only want to add paintView when I press the paint Button.
This works, but when I press it again to stop painting mode and remove the view from superview, the whole screen gets white.
How can I bypass that?

```
- (id)init
{
  ...
  [self.view addSubview:theScrollView];
  [theScrollView addSubview:thePDFView];

  drawImage = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
  [thePDFView addSubview:drawImage];

  paintView = [[PaintViewController alloc] initWithImage:drawImage andPath:pageString];
}

- (void) togglePainting:(NSNotification *)notif  {

if (!painting) {
    theScrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
    [thePDFView addSubview:paintView.view];
}
else {
    theScrollView.scrollEnabled = true;
    [thePDFView removeFromSuperview];
}

painting = !painting;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[thePDFView removeFromSuperview];
```

removes the whole view which was inside the scroll view leaving you nothing but the scrollview which does not have any subviews now. Hence your view is white. I think you wanted to remove only `paintView.view` so it should be `[paintView.view removeFromSuperview];`